# Highcharts - grouped column chart having different series size

Tags: javascript, json, html, highcharts

I have a JSON array each object in array represents a food item and its caloric value, calcium content etc.
Using Highcharts I want to plot a chart to show the calcium content of each food item grouped by its type.
So my Y-axis will be the calcium content present in the food item and X-axis will be the food item type.

I see examples of grouped/stacked charts in http://www.highcharts.com/demo but I am not able to map my JSON aray to the series format that highchart need.

Following is the categories array (This need to be my X-axis categories)

```
categories = ['Cereal Grains', 'Leafy Vegitables', 'Nuts and Seeds', 'Fruits', 'Roots and Tubers', 'Sea Foods', 'Sugars', 'Milk Products', 'Meat and Poultry', 'Condiments and Spices', 'Pulse and Legumes']
```

And the actual JSON array is as follows

```
[
  {
    'type': 'Cereal Grains',
    'item': 'Rice Flakes',
    'energy': 346,
    'calcium': 20,
    'iron': 20
  },
  {
    'type': 'Leafy Vegitables',
    'item': 'Agathi',
    'energy': 93,
    'calcium': 1130,
    'iron': 4
  },
  {
    'type': 'Leafy Vegitables',
    'item': 'Cabbage',
    'energy': 27,
    'calcium': 39,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Leafy Vegitables',
    'item': 'Lettuce',
    'energy': 21,
    'calcium': 50,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Leafy Vegitables',
    'item': 'Spinach',
    'energy': 26,
    'calcium': 73,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Leafy Vegitables',
    'item': 'Celery',
    'energy': 37,
    'calcium': 230,
    'iron': 6
  },
  {
    'type': 'Nuts and Seeds',
    'item': 'Almond',
    'energy': 655,
    'calcium': 230,
    'iron': 5
  },
  {
    'type': 'Nuts and Seeds',
    'item': 'GroundNut',
    'energy': 567,
    'calcium': 90,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Nuts and Seeds',
    'item': 'Cashewnut',
    'energy': 596,
    'calcium': 450,
    'iron': 6
  },
  {
    'type': 'Nuts and Seeds',
    'item': 'Walnut',
    'energy': 687,
    'calcium': 100,
    'iron': 3
  },
  {
    'type': 'Fruits',
    'item': 'Sapota',
    'energy': 98,
    'calcium': 28,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Fruits',
    'item': 'seethaphal',
    'energy': 104,
    'calcium': 17,
    'iron': 4
  },
  {
    'type': 'Fruits',
    'item': 'Pomegranate',
    'energy': 65,
    'calcium': 10,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Fruits',
    'item': 'Pine Apple',
    'energy': 46,
    'calcium': 9,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Fruits',
    'item': 'Lichi',
    'energy': 61,
    'calcium': 10,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Fruits',
    'item': 'Apple',
    'energy': 59,
    'calcium': 10,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Fruits',
    'item': 'Red Cherry',
    'energy': 64,
    'calcium': 24,
    'iron': 0
  },
  {
    'type': 'Fruits',
    'item': 'Water Melon',
    'energy': 16,
    'calcium': 11,
    'iron': 8
  },
  {
    'type': 'Roots and Tubers',
    'item': 'Carrot',
    'energy': 48,
    'calcium': 80,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Roots and Tubers',
    'item': 'Potato',
    'energy': 97,
    'calcium': 10,
    'iron': 0
  },
  {
    'type': 'Roots and Tubers',
    'item': 'Tapioca',
    'energy': 157,
    'calcium': 50,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Sea Foods',
    'item': 'Crab',
    'energy': 169,
    'calcium': 1606,
    'iron': 0
  },
  {
    'type': 'Sea Foods',
    'item': 'Prawn',
    'energy': 89,
    'calcium': 323,
    'iron': 5
  },
  {
    'type': 'Sea Foods',
    'item': 'Sardine',
    'energy': 101,
    'calcium': 90,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Sea Foods',
    'item': 'Mullet',
    'energy': 155,
    'calcium': 357,
    'iron': 4
  },
  {
    'type': 'Sugars',
    'item': 'Honey',
    'energy': 319,
    'calcium': 5,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Sugars',
    'item': 'Sago',
    'energy': 351,
    'calcium': 10,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Milk Products',
    'item': 'Cheese',
    'energy': 348,
    'calcium': 790,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Milk Products',
    'item': 'Curd',
    'energy': 60,
    'calcium': 149,
    'iron': 0
  },
  {
    'type': 'Milk Products',
    'item': 'Skimmed Milk',
    'energy': 29,
    'calcium': 120,
    'iron': 0
  },
  {
    'type': 'Meat and Poultry',
    'item': 'Egg-Duck',
    'energy': 181,
    'calcium': 70,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Meat and Poultry',
    'item': 'Egg-Hen',
    'energy': 173,
    'calcium': 60,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Meat and Poultry',
    'item': 'Pork',
    'energy': 114,
    'calcium': 30,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Meat and Poultry',
    'item': 'Mutton',
    'energy': 194,
    'calcium': 150,
    'iron': 2
  },
  {
    'type': 'Condiments and Spices',
    'item': 'Asafoetida',
    'energy': 297,
    'calcium': 690,
    'iron': 39
  },
  {
    'type': 'Condiments and Spices',
    'item': 'Cardamom',
    'energy': 229,
    'calcium': 130,
    'iron': 5
  },
  {
    'type': 'Condiments and Spices',
    'item': 'Fresh Ginger',
    'energy': 67,
    'calcium': 20,
    'iron': 3
  },
  {
    'type': 'Condiments and Spices',
    'item': 'Omum',
    'energy': 323,
    'calcium': 1525,
    'iron': 12
  },
  {
    'type': 'Condiments and Spices',
    'item': 'Garlic Dry',
    'energy': 145,
    'calcium': 30,
    'iron': 1
  },
  {
    'type': 'Pulse and Legumes',
    'item': 'Soyabean',
    'energy': 432,
    'calcium': 240,
    'iron': 10
  },
  {
    'type': 'Pulse and Legumes',
    'item': 'Lentil',
    'energy': 343,
    'calcium': 69,
    'iron': 7
  }
]
```

The categories are composed based on the `type` property of each object.
Now I'm confused how to build the series for the chart that will group each item properly. I'm expecting a graph like one it the demo [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic) or [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked).

The difference when compared to the demo samples is that my categories is having different number of objects. There is *only one item in Cereal Grains*, *5 in Leafy Vegetables*, *8 in Fruits* etc. So when I plot there will be different number of columns/stacks for each category. In the demo there are equal number of columns/stacks for categories.

Comment: The data array in highcharts expects a value for each category. If none exists then use 0 I guess

Comment: @eric how many objects I need to fill in the series array, whose `name` field is chosen as legend by Highcharts

Comment: Hi, Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Lucky I just forked the stacked demo to a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x6awtaed/5/). I'm stuck at building the `series` object. Just added the `Rice Flakes` with data value `20` which comes under the `Cereal Grains`. How to add the remaining categories?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x6awtaed/6/

Comment: @HalvorStrand Thanks a lot. Its awesome